# Find control from LayoutRoot in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a multiple textblocks on my usercontrol Layoutroot the problem is how can I find a particular TextBlock by its name?

Thanx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var myElement =
    ((FrameworkElement)System.Windows.Application.Current.RootVisual)
        .FindName("TextBlockName");
```

should work in this case, if the textblock has already been rendered.

To be able to easily traverse the visual tree more generally like @ColinE mentioned, you can also use the Silverlight toolkit.

```
// requires System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

var myElement = myRoot.GetVisualDescendants().OfType<TextBlock>()
    .Where(txb => txb.Name == "TextBlockName").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a UserControl, any element that you name via `x:Name` should be available to you as a field in your code-behind.

If you are not creating a UserControl, you can search the visual tree via [Linq to VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) ...

```
TextBlock block = LayoutRoot.Descendants<TextBlock>()
                            .Cast<TextBlock>()
                            .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Name == "TextBlockName");
```

Comment: When  I compile the above code it throws error LayoutRoot doesn't have option of descendent

Comment: Have you read the referenced page: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/ ? You must include "using LinqToVisualTree;"

Comment: +1 because it could be simply a matter of giving them an x:Name.

Comment: @BreakHead:  Consider this version of doing the same stuff: http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx

Answer (score 1):

hey Masn i was write some code and similiar conditions in my case that all ok.
this is the case (have many listbox and named variables diferenciated by number in final the name Example: listAttachment1,listAttachment2,listAttachment3,..,etc). To best explication show my code:

public void refreshAttachmentList(ListlistOfControlsRequest, int identifier)
        {

```
    string valueName = "attachmentsField_"+identifier;

        var mylistAttachment = ((FrameworkElement)System.Windows.Application.Current.RootVisual).FindName(valueName);
        ListBox listAttachRequest = mylistAttachment as ListBox;

        listAttachRequest.ClearValue(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
        listAttachRequest.ItemsSource = listOfAttachmentsControls;
        listAttachRequest.....all properties
```

}